# regex with negative matching (ie, find string that _doesn't_ match regex)

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I have a log file with the string "ERROR" on some lines. I want to delete every line that *doesn't* have ERROR so that I can see just what needs fixing. I was going to do something like the following in vim:

%s/!(ERROR)//

to replace non-error lines with an empty string.

I do not believe that standard regexes can do this, but maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the `:g!` command to delete every line that doesn't match.

```
:g!/ERROR/d
```

Comment: `:v/ERROR/d` is equivalent

Answer (score 8):

In vim, you can run any filter command on the text in the buffer. For example,

```
:%!grep ERROR
```

will replace the entire buffer with only the lines that match the given regular expression.

This is useful for more than just `grep`, for example you can sort the lines in the buffer with `:%!sort`. Or, you can do the same for any range of text using the `V` command to mark the block and then `:!filter-command` (vim will automatically fill in `'<,'>` for you to indicate the currently marked block).

Comment: +1 for a command that doesn't require leaving vim / redirecting into a different file

Comment: Maybe not the best of examples, as `:grep` and `:sort` do have built-in meanings in Vim (which are different than `:!grep` and `:!sort`, just to be confusing).

Answer (score 1):

if on *nix, you can use grep -v or awk

```
awk '!/ERROR/' file | more
```

on a windows machine, you can use findstr

```
findstr /v /c:ERROR file | more
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) worked.

Comment: Not a very useful answer without an example: `:%s/^\(\ERROR\)\@!$\n//g`. In Vim the `\@!` is the negative lookahead indicator, not the `(?!)` format from that link. The `:g!` answer is easier though.

Comment: I agree with @atomicules, but I'm nevertheless upvoting Alexander's answer because 'negative lookahead' is a useful term for further websearching.

Answer (score 0):

A negative matching regex will use ^
For eg. [^E] will match everything except E.

Comment: That's true, but such a regex will match every *character* that's not E, which is different from matching all *lines* that do not contain E. Also, such a negative match is awkward to extend beyond one character.